# Pyramid ranking in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to create a pyramid styled list of all users in my db.
It should look somewhat like this:

```
   01
  02 03
04 05 06
```

I tried playing arround with in_groups_of, which groups the elements in groups of x but even that doesn't work out correctly because when I chose in_groups_of(2) and put a div around that it gives me a div that contains two users. But I want a div for every user and the setup described above.

I know it must be sth like:

```
n=1
items per line = n
and after eachline n=n+1
```

but I dont know how to accomplish that in RoR.

Comment: Does this pyramid correspond to relations in the database (e.g. the top of the pyramid is the boss of the company), or is it just a nice way of displaying the list (regardless of any order).

Comment: At the moment it should only show all registered users. It probably orderes them by userID by default (using devise for user management).
Later it should be ordered by another column "user_ranking" as it is for a sports-ranking project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `shift` the array by a growing number each time to create a pyramid:

```
arr = %w(01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11)
n = 1
until arr.empty?
  edge = arr.shift(n)
  edge.fill('--', edge.length...n)
  puts edge.join(' ').center(20)
  n += 1
end
#         01         
#       02 03        
#      04 05 06      
#    07 08 09 10     
#  11 -- -- -- --
```

Note that in this method `arr` is destroyed while creating the pyramid, and it will be an empty array by the end of the iterations. If you want to keep it, you'll need to `dup` it before starting.

Comment: I tried this in my RoR app but while

`<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= user.name %>
<% end %>` gives me the users, all I get when I use


`<% n = 1 %>
<% until @users.empty? %>
<% edge = @users.shift(n) %>
<% edge.each do |user| %>
<%= user.name %>
<% end %>
<% n += 1 %>
<% end %>` is an error: _undefined method `shift' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f84847ccf80>_

Comment: @nucci `shift` is an `Array` API, try calling `users = @users.to_a` and go over that.

Comment: That worked just fine, thank you. Any idea how I can "fill up" the last row if there are fewer elements than needed?
So let's say I have 4 users, then user4 is the only entry in row number 3 and I need to fill up the row with 2 more "blank" elements to style it correctly.